# Rust Serde - Is it possible to map json data the could be in two different layouts back to a single struct?

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, json-deserialization, serde

The data I'm trying to map to my struct comes in two formats:

With `card_faces`, when there is more than one face to the card:

```
{
  "object": "card",
  "id": "some_id",
  "lang": "en",
  "released_at": "2012-02-03",
  "card_faces": [
    {
      "name": "some_name",
      "cost": "5",
      "ctype": "some_type",
      "colors": [
        "R",
        "B"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "another_name",
      "cost": "",
      "ctype": "another_type",
      "colors": [
        "R",
        "B"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "set_code": "some_code"
}
```

And without `card_faces`, when there is only one face (the face fields are just placed in the root):

```
{
  "object": "card",
  "id": "some_id",
  "lang": "en",
  "released_at": "2012-02-03",
  "name": "some_name",
  "cost": "5",
  "ctype": "some_type",
  "colors": [
    "R",
    "B"
  ],
  "set_code": "some_code"
}
```

I would like my struct to always have a `Vec<CardFace>` field. Something like:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Card {
  object: String,
  id: String,
  lang: String,
  released_at: String,
  faces: Vec<CardFace>,
  set_code: String,
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize these objects and coerce the face fields into the desired format or would I need to manipulate the json prior to deserializing?

Comment: I just wanted to add that whoever designed the JSON like that must have hated other people: Just please don't do that kids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using an intermediary `enum`:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum CardTmpDeser {
    Card {
        object: String,
        id: String,
        lang: String,
        released_at: String,
        card_faces: Vec<CardFace>,
        set_code: String,
    },
    SingleCard {
        object: String,
        id: String,
        lang: String,
        released_at: String,
        name: String,
        cost: String,
        ctype: String,
        colors: Vec<String>,
        set_code: String,
    },
}
```

With the `#[serde(untagged)]` attribute, you can transparently deserialize both kinds of data you have.

Now simply tag your actual structure with `#[serde(from = "CardTmpDeser")]`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(from = "CardTmpDeser")]
pub struct Card {
    object: String,
    id: String,
    lang: String,
    released_at: String,
    card_faces: Vec<CardFace>,
    set_code: String,
}
```

and implement `From<CardTmpDeser>` for `Card` and you're good to go! `serde` will automatically deserialize your data using `CardTmpDeser` but will transparently convert it to your final type.

([Permalink to the playground with full working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33ff080a7efd11fd484c5d08768e3453))